# How do I delay Android Room loading until after activity and prompts complete?

Tags: java, android, android-room

**Problem:** I'm receiving a `null` database name error. The Android Room database calls in my `MainActiity.class` proceed to execute though there is a prompt to let the user choose the database name.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm still learning Android, but I'm trying to work out in a separate app, the use of a master `Room` database to manage the use of multiple `Room` databases used by the app (this is a sandbox type of app to play with this idea). This database management functionality is working well but things are hard coded. So, I'm at the step where I'm wanting the user to have the ability, through the use of `sharedPreferences` and a custom `alert` prompts, to have the option to **create at install the first room database name** and add others thereafter. The option to add them later is not an issue as something will be loaded. However, on the intial app launch, I would like the user to have the option to create and name the first DB rather than a default be created -- which is not really that big a deal, but why have a potential default DB the user never uses. I could even develop a method of renaming, which I will, but it seems to make sense to allow the user to do this.

**What I have tried:** I've tried to create some methods to encapsulate and separate out the DB calls from the prompts, but the code still blows through to the DB code. I did some searching on delaying `Room` but couldn't find anything specific to it. I'm open to the wisdom of others.

**Code** again, this is just one activity since I'm playing with the idea... and learning at the same time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DB_INFO";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor settings;
    String databaseName;
    String prevDB;

    Button button;

    MasterDatabase masterDB;
    List<MasterDatabaseList> mdbList;
    ArrayList<BaseDatabase> bdbList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Current Database
    int currentBaseDBIndex = -1;
    BaseDatabase currentDB = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings = sharedPreferences.edit();
        setupOnClickActions();
        startChecks();
        Toast.makeText(this, "database: " + databaseName + "\r\n" + "prevDB: " + prevDB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void startChecks(){
        if(isFirstTime()) {
            databaseName = PopupDialog.AlertInputBox(this, "Enter Research Project Name",
                    "Without spaces or special characters, enter a name for your research project.");
            settings.putString("database", databaseName);
            settings.commit();
            settings.apply();
            startDBs();
        }else{
            databaseName = PopupDialog.AlertInputBox(this, "Enter Research Project Name",
                    "Without spaces or special characters, enter a new or existing name for your research project.");
            settings.putString("prevDB", sharedPreferences.getString("database", ""));
            settings.putString("database", databaseName);
            settings.commit();
            settings.apply();
            prevDB = sharedPreferences.getString("prevDB", "");
            startDBs();
        }
    }

    private void startDBs(){
        masterDB = MasterDatabase.getInstance(this);
        mdbList = masterDB.getMasterDao().getAllDatabases();

        // Add a DB if none exists
        if(mdbList.size()<1){
            addBaseDB("sample.db");
        }
        setCurrentIndexDBandDao(databaseName); /* Add some data to db1 IF it exists (it should) --------------------- */

        if (currentBaseDBIndex > -1 && currentDB.getBaseDao().count() < 1) {
            currentDB.getBaseDao().insert(new BaseTable("Added " + databaseName + " ... etc."));

        }

        /* Extract and Log Data for ALL the BaseDatabase databases i.e. db1 and db2 */
        for(MasterDatabaseList masterdb: masterDB.getMasterDao().getAllDatabases()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Database is " + masterdb.getDatabaseName());
            setCurrentIndexDBandDao(masterdb.getDatabaseName());
            if (currentBaseDBIndex > -1) {
                for(BaseTable bt: currentDB.getBaseDao().getAllBaseTables()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Extracted Base Table  row where MyData is" + bt.getMydata());
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // METHODS =========================================================================================================

    // Attempt to clear and reset SharedPreferences to a user first execution
    private void setupOnClickActions(){
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settings.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
                settings.clear();
                settings.commit();
                settings.apply();
            }
        });
    }

    /* Add a new Database
         Note that it assumes that it will now be the current
         so the current values are set */
    private void addBaseDB(String baseDBName) {
        masterDB.getMasterDao().insert(new MasterDatabaseList(baseDBName));
    }

    /* Build/ReBuild the 3 Lists according to the master database*/
    private void buildBaseLists() {
        bdbList.clear();
        mdbList = masterDB.getMasterDao().getAllDatabases();
        // Loop through the databases defined in the master database adding the database and dao to the respective lists
        for (MasterDatabaseList masterDB: masterDB.getMasterDao().getAllDatabases()) {
            BaseDatabase baseDB = BaseDatabase.getInstance(this, masterDB.getDatabaseName());
            bdbList.add(baseDB);
        }
    }

    /* Set the currentDB according to the database name*/
    private void setCurrentIndexDBandDao(String baseDBName) {
        currentBaseDBIndex = getListIndexByBaseDBName(baseDBName);
        if(currentBaseDBIndex == -1) {
            addBaseDB(baseDBName);
            buildBaseLists();
            currentBaseDBIndex = getListIndexByBaseDBName(baseDBName);
        }
        if (currentBaseDBIndex > -1) {
            buildBaseLists();
        }
        currentDB = bdbList.get(currentBaseDBIndex);
    }

    /* Get the index according to the database name passed*/
    private int getListIndexByBaseDBName(String baseDBName) {
        if(mdbList==null)
            mdbList = masterDB.getMasterDao().getAllDatabases();
        int rv = -1; // default to not found
        for(int i=0; i < mdbList.size();i++) {
            if (mdbList.get(i).getDatabaseName().equals(baseDBName)) {
                rv = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    /* Output all rows from the BaseTable for data extracted by the BaseDaos getAllBaseTables */
    private void logBaseData(List<BaseTable> baseTableList) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Current Database Index is " + currentBaseDBIndex + " DB name is " + mdbList.get(currentBaseDBIndex).getDatabaseName());
        for(BaseTable bt: baseTableList) {
            Log.d(TAG,"\tMyData value is " + bt.getMydata());
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstTime(){
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
            settings.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
            settings.commit();
            settings.apply();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**The BaseDatabase** - databaseName is where the error occurs because of the empty variable

```
@Database(
        entities = {BaseTable.class},
        version = 1
)
public abstract class BaseDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BaseDao getBaseDao();

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    public static BaseDatabase getInstance(Context context, String databaseName) {
        BaseDatabase instance = null;
        if (databaseName != null) {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, BaseDatabase.class, databaseName)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: Use a observer subscriber like data structure like liveData etc and listen to changes when data is fetched.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - ` BaseDatabase` initialization in the `buildBaseLIst` within the `for` loop.

Comment: @Anshul - Thanks, I hadn't tried `Observer`, I will read up.

Comment: @svstackoverflow Please give the actual line of code rather than a verbal description of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with 2 activities. The first **MainActivity** that

- displays a list of the available databases (none at first)

  - clicking on a database allows it to be selected (it is not accessed or created (if new))
- allows a database to be added, by entering it's name in the EditText, to the available databases (it is not created or accessed).
- allows a second activity to be passed the database name where the activity can then open the database (creating it if it doesn't exist).

  - note that the database isn't accessed.

So first the MasterDatabaseList class (entity) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = MasterDatabaseList.TABLE_NAME,
        indices = { @Index(value = MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME, unique = true)
        }
)
class MasterDatabaseList {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "masterdatabaselist";
    public static final String COl_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_DATABASE_NAME = "databasename";
    public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = new String[]{
            COl_ID, COL_DATABASE_NAME
    };
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = COl_ID)
    Long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_DATABASE_NAME)
    String databaseName;

    public MasterDatabaseList() {}
    @Ignore
    public MasterDatabaseList(String databaseName) {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }
    public void setDatabaseName(String databaseName) {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }
}
```

- similar to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197676/can-android-room-manage-multiple-databases-and-create-databases-from-a-template/69201487?noredirect=1#comment124105618_69201487) (but note some added constants)

**MasterDatabaseDao**

```
@Dao
abstract class MasterDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(MasterDatabaseList masterDatabaseList);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM masterdatabaselist")
    abstract List<MasterDatabaseList> getAllDatabases();

    Cursor getAllDatabasesAsCursor() {
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(
                new String[]{
                        BaseColumns._ID, /* Cursor Adapter must use _id column for id) */
                        MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME
                },
                0
        );
        for(MasterDatabaseList m: getAllDatabases()) {
            matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{m.id,m.databaseName});
        }
        return matrixCursor;
    }
}
```

- Note the new method that gets the list of available databases as a Cursor (for the ListView)
- **MasterDatabase**

  @Database(
  entities = {MasterDatabaseList.class},
  version = 1
  )
  abstract class MasterDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
  abstract MasterDao getMasterDao();

  ```
    static volatile MasterDatabase instance = null;
    public static MasterDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,MasterDatabase.class,"master.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
  ```

  }
- unchanged from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197676/can-android-room-manage-multiple-databases-and-create-databases-from-a-template/69201487?noredirect=1#comment124105618_69201487)

2nd Activity **UseSelectedDatabase**

```
public class UseSelectedDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASEID = "database_id";
    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASENAME = "database_name";

    long mDatabaseId;
    String mDatabaseName;
    TextView mDatabaseBeingUsed;
    Button mDoneButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_use_selected_database);
        mDatabaseBeingUsed = this.findViewById(R.id.database_name);
        mDoneButton = this.findViewById(R.id.done);


        mDatabaseId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASEID,-1);
        mDatabaseName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASENAME);
        mDatabaseBeingUsed.setText(mDatabaseName);
        setDoneButton();

        /*
            can now get an instance of the database
         */

    }
    
    private void setDoneButton() {
        mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- This doesn't access the database but just receives the database name and id in the master database. i.e. just shows that you can pass all the information required to access the database.

2nd Activities layout **activity_use_selected_database.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UseSelectedDatabase">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/database_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Database Set?"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Initial Activity **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MasterDatabase mMasterDB;
    MasterDao mMasterDBDao;
    EditText mDBToAdd;
    Button mAddDB,mUseSelectedDatabase;
    ListView mDatabaseList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mCsr;
    long mSelectedDatabaseId = 0;
    String mSelectedDatabaseName = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBToAdd = this.findViewById(R.id.database_name);
        mAddDB = this.findViewById(R.id.addDatabase);
        mUseSelectedDatabase = this.findViewById(R.id.useSelectedDatabase);
        mDatabaseList = this.findViewById(R.id.database_list);

        mMasterDB = MasterDatabase.getInstance(this);
        mMasterDBDao = mMasterDB.getMasterDao();


        setUpAddDBButton();
        setUpUseSelectedDatabaseButton();
        setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
    }

    private void setUpAddDBButton() {
        mAddDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mDBToAdd.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    if (mMasterDBDao.insert(new MasterDatabaseList(mDBToAdd.getText().toString())) > 0) {
                        mDBToAdd.setText("");
                        setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void setUpUseSelectedDatabaseButton() {
        mUseSelectedDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mSelectedDatabaseId > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),UseSelectedDatabase.class);
                    intent.putExtra(UseSelectedDatabase.INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASEID, mSelectedDatabaseId);
                    intent.putExtra(UseSelectedDatabase.INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASENAME,mSelectedDatabaseName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setOrRefreshDatabaseList() {
        mCsr = mMasterDBDao.getAllDatabasesAsCursor();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this.getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mCsr,
                    new String[]{MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mDatabaseList.setAdapter(mSCA);
            mDatabaseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                /* Handle Clicking on an Item (i.e. prepare UseSelected Button) */
                @SuppressLint("Range")
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    mSelectedDatabaseId = l;
                    if (l > 0) {
                        mSelectedDatabaseName = mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME));
                        mUseSelectedDatabase.setText(mSelectedDatabaseName);
                        mUseSelectedDatabase.setClickable(true);
                    } else {
                        mUseSelectedDatabase.setText("NO DATEBASE SELECTED");
                        mUseSelectedDatabase.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr.close();
    }
}
```

Initial Activity's layout **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/database_name"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="">
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addDatabase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Database"
        >
    </Button>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/database_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/useSelectedDatabase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NO SELECTED DATABASE"
        android:clickable="false"
        >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Demo**

When first run MainActivity displays :-

[image]

i.e. no available databases (clicking buttons does nothing).

Database Test001 entered into Edit Text and then Add Database clicked :-

[image]

- at this stage the Test001 database has not been created. However the MasterDatabase has been created and the Test001 row has been added (i.e. at some time the database could be opened and created if it doesn't already exist) :-

[image]

Test001 is clicked :-

[image]

- The Use Selected button has been changed to Test001 (perhaps should be Use Test001).
- Still the Test001 database hasn't been accessed at all, as there is no need.

Database Test002 is entered into the Edit Text (cleared after adding) and Add Database is clicked :-

[image]

- Note if an existing database is entered into the Edit Text it will NOT be added and the Text Box will not be cleared.

Test002 is clicked, the button changes to Test002 and the button is clicked, starting the 2nd activity :-

[image]

- The database isn't opened or accessed (i.e. further demonstrating waiting and doing things)

The DONE button is clicked returning to the first activity. Still the database has not been opened/accessed BUT with the other code (Base???? clases etc) could be (probably in the UseSelectedDatabase activity).

**Extra** As proof of concept the the BaseTable??? classes from the previous question were added, as were some new  User??? classes with  **BaseDatabase** being :-

```
@Database(
        entities = {BaseTable.class,User.class},
        version = 1
)
abstract class BaseDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract BaseDao getBaseDao();
    abstract UserDao getUserDao();

    public static BaseDatabase getInstance(Context context, String databaseName) {

        BaseDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, BaseDatabase.class, databaseName)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }
}
```

With the following added to the **UseSelectedDatabase** activity:-

```
    ....

    /*
        can now get an instance of the database
     */

    db = BaseDatabase.getInstance(this,mDatabaseName);
    baseDao = db.getBaseDao();
    userDao = db.getUserDao();

    baseDao.insert(new BaseTable("X"));
    userDao.insert(new User("Snowman","Fred","Wlibur","Bloggs","password",0));

    List<BaseTable> baseTableList = baseDao.getAllBaseTables();
    List<User> userList = userDao.getAllUsers();
```

Restarting the App selecting Test001 and then Test002 results in the database being shown as :-

[image]

i.e. Test001, albeit it closed, has obviously been created as has Test002.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I will try not to let you right the whole app, lol! I will review this and provide feedback. Thanks for all your help with this and prior. I learned a lot from them.

Comment: Ok, reviewed. As you probably saw, I modified some of the previous question example you provided (again, thanks). Reiterating to confirm, clicking the `Add Database` as many times just adds a name to the `MasterDatabase` and adds it to the `ListView`  which is refreshed every time but that is all. Selecting a DB on the `ListView` changes the 2nd `Button` name, and if that is clicked, starts the 2nd `Activity` creating the actual **Base** database. However, the other database names remain in the `ListView` regardless whether they are created -- correct? This is good... just confirming.

Comment: @svstackoverflow yes

Comment: I wanted followup for the benefit of MikeT and others that I was able to successfully implement the suggested multi-database management system along with his help on my previous question (foundational to this one) found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197676/can-android-room-manage-multiple-databases-and-create-databases-from-a-template