# How to load a different database file with Room?

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-room

### Goal

I have an app with plenty of data, with a switch button, which switch the language (french or english) of the entire app. However, **some of my data are stored in a Room database**. I have two `.db` files : `database_fr.db` and `database_en.db`.

Let's say the app is currently in french, with the `database_fr.db` loaded. When the switch button is pressed, I want the app to use the other `.db` file, to display all the data in english.

### What I have tried

I followed [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#7) to get familiar with Room, so this is how I loaded the database :

```java
@Database(entities = {/* blabla...*/}, version = 1, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class RoomDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {


   /* the Daos */

   private static volatile RoomDatabase INSTANCE;
   private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
   static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

   static RoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null || currentLocaleIsDifferentFromWantedLocale()) {
            synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null || currentLocaleIsDifferentFromWantedLocale()) {
                    // This is where the db files are loaded
                    if(localeWanted().equals("fr")){
                        // Load the french database
                        Log.i("French db file loaded !");
                        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                RoomDatabase.class, "database")
                                .createFromAsset("database/database_fr.db")
                                .build();
                    }
                    else if(localeWanted().equals("en")){
                        // Load the english database
                        Log.i("English db file loaded !");
                        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                RoomDatabase.class, "database")
                                .createFromAsset("database/database_en.db")
                                .build();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

and then call this method `getdatabase()` in the constructor of the `RoomRepository.java`

```java
 RoomRepository(Application application) {
        db = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        /* other variables */
 }
```

to finally access it in my Activities with the variable

```java
RoomViewModel roomViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RoomViewModel.class);
```

When the switch button is pressed, I modify the Locale and refresh the current Activity.

### The problem

All the texts stored in `strings.xml` files are displayed in the good language, but all the data stored in the `.db` file remains in french (default language).

The log `"English db file loaded !"` is displayed in my terminal so I know the code was executed.

### Question

How to update the `.db` file loaded efficiently ? I feel like I have to uninstall / re-install the app to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the singleton approach will only even build one of the databases. Once an instance has been retrieved then **INSTANCE** will no longer be null, so will return the already built database.

Here's an example of multiple databases but intended for an unknown number (and hence a master database used to store the known/created databases). It does allow switching between databases. So you might be able to adapt/simplify this to suite your needs.

[Can Android Room manage multiple databases and create databases from a template database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197676/can-android-room-manage-multiple-databases-and-create-databases-from-a-template/69201487#69201487)